# scipy minimization of a (2,2) array

Tags: arrays, optimization, numpy, matrix

Given matrix `a = [[1,2], [3,1]]` I tried to minimize the function square norm
of **a*x** where x is supposed to be a **(2,2) array** ---this is only a toy example---
by using the code below. However, I obtain from the console the following 
error message:

```
"    return np.linalg.norm(np.dot(a, x))**2 
ValueError: matrices are not aligned "
```

I will really appreciate an explanation. Thanks

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

a = np.array([[1, 2],[3, 1]])

def func_obj(x):
    return np.linalg.norm(np.dot(a, x))**2 


def func_deriv(x):
     """ Derivative of objective function """
     result = np.zeros([2, 2])
     for i in range(2):
        for j in range(2):
            for k in range(2):
                result[i,j] = result[i, j] + 2*(np.dot(a[k,:],x[:,j]))*a[k,i]
     return result


res = minimize(func_obj, [[1, -1],[-1,1]], jac = func_deriv, 
               method = 'SLSQP', options = {'disp':True})

print (res.x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the minimization function wants the parameters as a 1D-list. You are giving it a 2x2 matrix, and expect that it gives you one back.
Adding simple `reshape()` calls to unpack the parameters fixes the issue:

```
def func_obj(x):
    x = x.reshape(2,2)
    return np.linalg.norm(np.dot(a, x))**2 


def func_deriv(x):
     """ Derivative of objective function """
     x = x.reshape(2,2)
     result = np.zeros([2, 2])
     for i in range(2):
        for j in range(2):
            for k in range(2):
                result[i,j] = result[i, j] + 2*(np.dot(a[k,:],x[:,j]))*a[k,i]
     return result

x0 = np.array([[1, -1],[-1,1]]).reshape(-1)
res = minimize(func_obj, x0, jac = func_deriv, 
               method = 'SLSQP', options = {'disp':True})
```